# WPF RichTextBox format certain parts of the text based on selection in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have a WPF application which uses user definable custom formulas, which are stored as strings in a format like this.
"[MR:123]+[MR:456]"

When reviewing the result, I would like to display the formula which produced the result, in a RichTextBox control.  I am also going to list the source items for the calculation in a DataGrid.  I would like the various parts of the formula in the RichTextBox to change format (i.e. bold or change the color) when the corresponding row in the source items grid is selected.  A little bit like what happens in Excel.

So for example in the formula above, I would have 2 rows in the source items grid. "[MR:123]" and "[MR:456]".  When the user clicks on row "[MR:456]" I would like to highlight that part of the formula in the RichTextBox.

Something like the mockup sample in the link
[Mockup Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPDeJ.png)

Any suggestions or recommendations would be appreciated.  I'm fairly new to WPF.  I am using syncfusion controls generally, but happy for this situation to use the standard WPF RichTextBox control.  Or any other standard or syncfusion control that someone can suggest which would work better.

Comment: Sound like you want to dynamically fill your wpf richtextbox. [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28640459/1758906)

Comment: Not so much dynamically fill the text box as the text box gets populated a single time, by a parent record and I then want to highlight the parts of the text in the text box which relate to the selected child record in a grid control